# My POS Printer model is not listed in my SetupPOS.exe

Tags: java, windows-installation

I've written a Point of Sale app in Java which uses an Epson printer (model TM-T20) and a cash drawer. I'm on Windows 8.

I am trying to install all the necessary files to print a receipt.

On a completely clean drive, i did the following in order:

1. I installed jre1.8.0_73.
2. I set the path environment variable to the jre bin directory.
3. I copied the src\jpos folder from the JCL (Java config loader) into the jre lib ext directory.
4. I installed Java advanced Imaging (jai) and copied the 2 required jar files into the jre lib ext directory.
5. Next I installed the Epson APD (printer driver). During this process, I plugged in my usb printer and turned it on as instructed.
6. Then I ran the Epson JavaPOS ADK 1141.exe. This installs JavaPOS services.
7. I checked the JavaPOS service files are in the jre lib ext directory.

JavaPOS installed correctly.

I then run SetupPOS.exe to create my jpos.xml file.

All seems perfect until I click the device model combo box and my model is not listed. Why?

I have installed everything correctly on the same box previously (before a complete reset) without any problem but It was a while ago and I don't recall how I did it.

I suspect it might have to do with timing of plugging in the printer or It may be something else. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reset my drive again after that previous attempt and made 2 changes to the above.

1. I downloaded a fresh Epson_javaPOS ADK.exe from the Epson website in case mine was corrupted.
2. I followed the same steps above but this time in the following order. 1.2.3.4.6.7.5

It worked.